# What is a good way to copy data from one Cassandra ColumnFamily to another on the same Keyspace (like SQL's INSERT INTO)?

Tags: migration, nosql, cassandra

Trying to find a way to easily transfer all the rows from a Cassandra ColumnFamily/Table to another.

The `COPY` command, as I understand, is a good option.  However, as it dumps all the data to `.csv` on disk and then loads it back, I can't help but wonder if there is a better way to do it in-engine.

A specific example of what I mean would be the `INSERT * FROM my_table INTO my_other_table` available in many `SQL` databases.  Of course, I realize that Cassandra is NoSQL and therefore does not to work the same way - but it seems like something which might be available.

What is a good way to accomplish this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 11):

```
cqlsh -k mykeyspace -e 'COPY fromTable(columnNames) TO STDOUT' | head -n -1 | 
cqlsh -k mykeyspace -e 'COPY toTable(columnNames) FROM STDIN'
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting.  However, I'd be concerned about character escaping and other issues, especially when dealing with certain types of data.  Is that a concern at all?

Comment: Good idea, but as @JuanCarlosCoto said, it doesn't work with certain data types. I tried it on a table with a blob column and it crashed on a newline character.

Comment: On cassandra 2.1.2 I had to modify the command to be head -n -2 because the ouput of COPY includes two lines at the end that need to be trimmed. It was still working, but it got mad about the empty line at the end.

Comment: Note - Only use COPY FROM to import datasets that have less than 2 million rows. To import large datasets, use the Cassandra bulk loader.

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at `sstableloader`?

- https://web.archive.org/web/20150215110737/http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html
- https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/toolsSStables/toolsBulkloader.html